# Delete end part of a string

Tags: matlab

I have a string called

```
'280319_name_key, 1.txt'
```

How can I use regexprep for it to look like:

```
'280319_name_key'
```

Can anyone explain to me the basics of regexprep because I'm a little confusing in how to make the most out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regexprep is great if you want to remove say all spaces from a string. Or you need to change all filenames that end with .txt to .cs or whatever.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html

So in your case it would look like:

```
newStr = regexprep('280319_name_key, 1.txt',', 1.txt','')
```

Or if you understand working with strings alone better, I would do this instead:

```
x = '280319_name_key, 1.txt';
new_x = x(1:end-7);
```

Do what you understand, would be what I recommend.

Answer (score 1):

In simple cases like this, there is no need for `regexprep`. You can use [`strtok`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html?s_tid=doc_ta):

```
str = '280319_name_key, 1.txt';
strtok(str,',')
```

which is equivalent to:

```
str(1:strfind(str,',')-1)
```

Comment: Whilst ok for occasional use strtok is significantly slower than regexprep. I had a function that needed to process 80,000 strings in a cell array. The profiler showed strtok taking 12.5 seconds, switching to regexprep reduced that to 7seconds.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. Any idea why it's so slow?

Comment: Sorry don't know why - it was just a comment in Yair Altmans book Accelerating MATLAB and it worked for my function. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tXPOBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA148&ots=xWD1RHNP5H&dq=matlab%20strtok%20vs%20regexprep&pg=PA148#v=onepage&q=matlab%20strtok%20vs%20regexprep&f=false